# import csv file with where clause on name start with 2 characters

Tags: mysql, csv

i want to load data into my mysql table only the name that start with "a.%" not all lines...

The code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'asd.csv' 
INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(name, date)
SET batch = 'asd.csv'
```

i need a where clause.. like `Where name LIKE 'a.%'`

Comment: where is the same question on stack? if you can link it i will delete it.

Comment: Before asking any question, research from your self.

Comment: done that, didn't find, normally i search if I don't see any answers, i put a question.